# StackBuffer - awesome StackOverflow interface (HTML5, CSS3)

Tags: app, website

### Screenshot of StackBuffer.com interface

[image]

### About

StackBuffer is open source project providing **HTML5 and CSS3** interface for StackOverflow API. This project is actually **experiment** trying to prove that you can write only HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript without need to do any backend programming. This app is targeted mostly to developers to see what can be done in short period of time with new HTML5 and CSS3. Consider it example application.

The application is pure HTML5 and CSS3 with jQuery running JSONP against StackOverflow API.

#### License

MIT License, It's open source.

#### Demo

You can find the demo at [stackbuffer.com](http://stackbuffer.com/)

#### Platform

Currently running only on Google Chrome Browser.

### Contact

Ladislav Martincik, martincik.com or twitter @martincik

### Code

Languages:

1. HTML5
2. CSS3
3. Javascript

Frameworks:

1. jQuery
2. Underscore.js
3. Less.js
4. Mustache.js
5. Prettify.js

You can fork it on github at github.com/martincik/StackBuffer

Comment: I embedded the image for you.

Comment: Pretty cool that you are able to make apps with no server at all these days.

Comment: Really cool! Impressively demonstrates how far you can go with frontend technologies only nowadays.

Comment: Please consider listing StackBuffer on [StackList](http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com/).

Comment: This should be the official Stackoverflow chrome web app (with slight modifications to the colour to make it look official, eg more orange)